# How do I access the selected number of an Enum Property?

Tags: python, interface

I created an Enum Property in a Property Group. It is using a callback function to be filled.

```
class MatProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    
    color_enum : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name= "Color",
        description= "Select the color of the material",
        items=enum_color_names(),
        update=udpate_color_enum
    )
```

of course I register that property and also create a Pointer Property

```
reg_classes = [MatProperties, MatPanel, CreateMat]
        
def register():
    for c in reg_classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)
        
        bpy.types.Scene.PM_MatProp = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type= MatProperties)
    
def unregister():
    for c in reg_classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)
        del bpy.types.Scene.PM_MatProp
```

inside the panel I am using the entries of that enum and everything works fine

```
class MatPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Mat"
    bl_idname = "My_PT_MatPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Tools'
            
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        layout.prop(context.scene.PM_MatProp, "color_enum")

        row = layout.row()
        CM = row.operator("object.createmat_operator", text="Create Material")
        row = layout.row()
        CM.color_name = context.scene.PM_MatProp.color_enum
```

**My question: How do I access the number/index of the currently selected entry of the enum?**

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a stringified integer index as your enum identifiers and then just do `int(context.scene.PM_MatProp.color_enum)` but you didn't post the code for `enum_color_names` sor I'll assume there is a reason why you can't do that.

Assuming `enum_color_names` returns an iterable of string tuples under the form of `(identifier, name, description)` you can get the index of the selected element by looking at the first element of each tuple and comparing it with the current value of the enum property.

```
identifiers = [values[0] for values in enum_color_names()]
index = identifiers.index(context.scene.PM_MatProp.color_enum)
```

If for some reason you can't run `enum_color_names` too often (pulling from a database with poor query times, etc.) you can get the already registered items of an enum with `holder.bl_rna.properties["my_enum"].enum_items`.

Do note there might be a mismatch with the actual result of `enum_color_names` though if for some reason the items change inbetween two calls.

```
enum_items = context.scene.PM_MatProp.bl_rna.properties["color_enum"].enum_items
identifiers = [enum_item.identifier for enum_item in enum_items]
index = identifiers.index(context.scene.PM_MatProp.color_enum)
```

[link to bpy.tpyes.EnumProperty doc](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.EnumProperty.html?highlight=enum_items)

[Link to bpy.types.EnumPropertyItem doc](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.EnumPropertyItem.html#bpy.types.EnumPropertyItem.identifier)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Gorgious.
Yes, `enum_color_names` returns an iterable in the form of `[('COLOR', 'Color', "")]` . I also tried to make the identifier a stringified integer, but then I have the problem that I can't access the name of the enum element (which I also need).
But the second method of comparing the tuples with the current value of `color_enum` seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Braindrain85 Happy to help ! Also note in your `register` and `unregister` that you're calling the `bpy.types.Scene.PM_MatProp` property creator and destructor for each class in your class holder, which will throw an error on unregister I think. You should put it outside of the `for` loop